# Checking combinations of letters in a string against a dataset

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to build a small app that finds different phonemic units in a word. I have a data set of phonemes that looks like this:

```
export const consonants = [
  {
    consonantSound: 's',
    spellings: [
      { spelling: 's', example: 'sun' },
      { spelling: 'ss', example: 'class' },
      { spelling: 'c', example: 'cell' },
      { spelling: 'ce', example: 'voice' },
      { spelling: 'house', example: 'se' },
      { spelling: 'scent', example: 'sc' },
    ],
  },
  {
    consonantSound: 'sh',
    spellings: [
      { spelling: 'sh', example: 'ship' },
      { spelling: 'ch', example: 'machine' },
    ],
  },
[...]
]
```

For the word `laugh` for example I would need to search through the data set until I found spellings that matched l, au, gh (which are the phonemic units of that word /l/ /ar/ /f/)

I have tried this but it seems pretty off the mark and now I am stumped

```
export const phonemeCheck = (word) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    let chunk = word.slice(i)
    for (let i = 0; i < consonants.length; i++) {
      let consonantSpelling = consonants[i].spellings[0].spelling
      console.log(chunk, consonantSpelling)
    }
  }
}
```

I think what I need to achieve is something that iterates through the word like so:

```
"l","la", "lau", "laug", "laugh", "a", "au", "aug", "augh", "u", "ug", "ugh", "g", "gh".
```

Wondering if anyone could provide some guidance?

Answer (score 0):

This is for the chunking part. If that is not enough, could you edit your question to add a minimal example and expected output?

```js
const phonemeCheck = (word) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < word.length - i; j++) {
      let chunk = word.substring(i, i + j + 1);
      console.log(chunk);
    }
  }
}

phonemeCheck("abcd");
```